# Postgre triggers saves t and f instead of true and false

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a trigger on a table to audit the changes but there is some problem related to a boolean data type that is saved into an audit table.

```
create table user {
  email text,
  active boolean
}
```

I want to audit the changes in the above table like when a user's active status changes from true to false and save it to another table. Below is the audit table structure.

```
create table audit_table {
   column_name text,
   old_value text,
   new_value text
}
```

To do this I have created a trigger but when I see the **audit_table** the true and false values are stored as t and f.

Comment: Pls. post your trigger function

Comment: You may use [this](https://github.com/stefanov-sm/Postgres-generic-audit-trigger) generic audit trigger to solve your particular issue and other ones of similar nature.